# Handling date formatting in oracle for NULL and 0's

Tags: sql, oracle, date-formatting

I am trying to parse a record into a table. The date in the
 record is of type 0cyymmdd c -> century(0:19,1:20)

ex: if date is00900201 it should be converted as 1990-02-01(yyy-mm-dd)

To do this I am initially loading the data coming in record to a
 varchar column and then formatting it using the following query:

```
UPDATE TABLE

DATE= CASE SUBSTR((DT_1),2,1) 

WHEN '0' THEN TO_DATE('19' || SUBSTR(DT_1,3),'yyyy-mm-dd')

WHEN '1' THEN TO_DATE('20' || SUBSTR(DT_1,3),'yyyy-mm-dd')

ELSE NULL

END
```

In the table DT(DATE), DT_1(VARCHAR)
But the record need not have date always, it might also have either
blank spaces or 0's in that case this query fails.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: If the DT_1 field have null or Zero at that time do you want to replace field with any default dates??

Comment: Literal doesn't math format string as we will be doing TO_DATE(00000000);

Comment: I don't want to load any default value I just want to skip loading data in to DT at that time

Comment: Before your update, run these updates: `UPDATE TABLE SET DT_1 = NULL WHERE DT_1 = '00000000'` and `UPDATE TABLE SET DT_1 = TRIM(DT_1)`. These will set invalid dates to NULL. Then you will find all the other invalid date cases.

Comment: thanks ..sorry for the late update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have  to update all the rows. To handle the cases where the date value could be **zeroes** or **spaces**, you could add a filter condition using **TRANSLATE** function.

```
WHERE translate(column_name, '#0 ','#') IS NOT NULL
```

For example,

**Setup**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(A VARCHAR2(8), b DATE);

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(A) VALUES('00900201');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(A) VALUES('01150820');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(A) VALUES('        ');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(A) VALUES('00000000');

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

A        B
-------- ---------
00900201
01150820

00000000
```

**UPDATE** statement

```
SQL> UPDATE t
  2   SET b = CASE
  3           WHEN SUBSTR(A, 2, 1) = '0'
  4              THEN to_date('19'
  5                   ||SUBSTR(A, 3), 'YYYYMMDD')
  6           WHEN SUBSTR(A, 2, 1) = '1'
  7              THEN to_date('20'
  8                   ||SUBSTR(A, 3), 'YYYYMMDD')
  9           ELSE NULL
 10           END
 11  WHERE translate(A, '#0 ','#') IS NOT NULL
 12  /

2 rows updated.
```

**Validation**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

A        B
-------- ---------
00900201 01-FEB-90
01150820 20-AUG-15

00000000

SQL>
```

So, it updated the required 2 rows having correct date values. Rest other rows it updated as NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Small modifications to your code. These will work if dt1 field will have 0's or nulls also.

```
UPDATE TABLE a

set a.DATE_column= CASE  

WHEN SUBSTR((DT_1),2,1)='0' THEN TO_DATE('19' || SUBSTR(DT_1,3),'yyyy-mm-dd')

WHEN SUBSTR((DT_1),2,1)=1 THEN TO_DATE('20' || SUBSTR(DT_1,3),'yyyy-mm-dd')
when (dt_1 = '0') or (dt_1 = null) 
 then null
ELSE NULL

END
```

Comment: If you have any other cases other than 0's and nulls then edit the above code based on that.

Comment: thanks this query works fine ..sorry for the late update